# how to design the redis key for relational database

Tags: redis

I'm migrating from oracle to redis. I have a table with four columns: A B C V
whose unique key is `A+B+C`.

The possible queries are:

1. `select * from tableName where A = a and B = b and C = c`
2. `select * from tableName where A = a and C = c`
3. `select * from tableName where A = a and B = b`

My question is how to design the redis's key space?

First I do it like this:

```
a:b:c=v
```

It simply solves the first query, but how about the 2nd and 3rd queries?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there may be some conceptual problems with your understanding or mine.  The queries you list as examples for operations you hope to accomplish are a bit misleading.  i.e. `select *` from whatever, implies possibly multiple columns or rows.  You will get one value for each key.  for any unique `a:b:c` only one `v` exists.  Are you attempting to get a different value when you look at key `a:b` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a:b:c that you are talking about is a key in redis. you can do

keys a:b:* to achieve this requirement.

If you give keys a:*:c it will return all keys matching that pattern, then get all those values with MGET method.